# Excel conditional formatting based on if it is in this currently displayed month

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am creating a work calendar and I want it to Grey out the Days of the week that are NOT part of the currently displayed month.  I have the First Day of the Month Displayed in Cell A1

How can I make the Cell Monday in Cell B3 and the Cell in B4 to have a grey background?

I know this is simple but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show example of excel sheet so far as I am not entirely clear what you mean? Is Month in A1 written as Jan or 01/01/11 or Jan-2010 for example? Also, is B3 = "Monday" or does it have a date and you are just displaying the weekday?

Comment: Here is an example where the color is light green...  http://nsnd.com/Excel_question1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, do the following:

1. Select cell A2:G13 (i.e the dates you want to format)
2. Now select **Format > Conditional Formatting...**
3. In the first drop down menu select **Formula Is**
4. In the next textbox enter this formula: `=MONTH($A$1)<>MONTH(A2)`
5. Now set the formatting you want for cells that do not match date in cell A1

This formula works by simply checking the month number of the date.

Note also that the formula check for inequality of dates i.e. if date is not in same month as that in cell A1 then format a different color.

If you also want to add a format for dates that do match then simply add another condition in the conditional formatting box and use `=MONTH($A$1)=MONTH(A2)`

Answer (score 1):

Home > Styles > Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules > A Date Occuring... > This Month

Obviously if you go this route, you would make the whole calendar year gray and then set the conditional formatting to make the current month white.

Comment: I know how to do that... but I want it to be able to pick a month any month. put in A1 4/1/2011 and then I want it to grey out any dates like 3/27/2011,3/28/2011,3/28/2011, etc but I am only going to show around a month of dates.  In other words this current month is January not march so I can not use current month.